# Swift 3 Horizontal Multiple UIScrollView - Different Speeds

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiscrollview

I have created two UIScrollViews ( One named scrollView and one named scrollLevel4 )

when I move scrollLevel4, I can get scrollView to move at the same speed using :-

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollLevel4: UIScrollView) {

    scrollView.contentOffset.x = scrollLevel4.contentOffset.x


}
```

However If I want to move scrollView at a different pace, not sure what to do, whenever I add anything to the end of line :

```
scrollView.contentOffset.x = scrollLevel4.contentOffset.x
```

it crashes, even a simple + 10, same pace, staggered offset, still crashes

also tried .scrollRectToVisible() method

Thoughts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the error or your code it's hard to say for sure, but most likely you are setting the same delegate for *both* scrollViews. When you drag `scrollLevel4`, it triggers a scroll on `scrollView`, so you get an infinite loop and eventually a crash.

If you want to use the same delegate on both scrollViews, you'll need to check which one was passed before operating on them. Here's a basic working implementation. Open a new single view project and replace the code in ViewController.swift with:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var imageView1: UIImageView!
    var imageView2: UIImageView!

    var scrollView1: UIScrollView!
    var scrollView2: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageView1 = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "image.jpg"))
        imageView2 = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "image.jpg"))

        scrollView1 = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)))
        scrollView1.contentSize = imageView1.bounds.size
        scrollView1.addSubview(imageView1)
        view.addSubview(scrollView1)

        scrollView2 = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 210), size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)))
        scrollView2.contentSize = imageView2.bounds.size
        scrollView2.addSubview(imageView2)
        view.addSubview(scrollView2)

        scrollView2.delegate = self
        scrollView1.delegate = self
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrolled: UIScrollView) {
        // both scrollViews call this when scrolled, so determine which was scrolled before adjusting
        if scrolled === scrollView1 {
            scrollView2.contentOffset.x = scrolled.contentOffset.x + 100
        } else if scrolled === scrollView2 {
            scrollView1.contentOffset.x = scrolled.contentOffset.x - 100
        }
    }

}
```

Note that whatever modification you apply to the offset of one, you have to apply the exact inverse (or nothing at all) to the other. Otherwise you'll have an infinite loop of back and forth scrolling ending in a crash.